# How to define the vector field $\hat{X}$ on a manifold $M$ defined by an element $X$ in a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, vector-fields

I read [a paper](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=%68%74%74%70%73%3a%2f%2f%77%77%77%2e%65%6d%73%2d%70%68%2e%6f%72%67%2f%6a%6f%75%72%6e%61%6c%73%2f%73%68%6f%77%5f%70%64%66%2e%70%68%70%3f%69%73%73%6e%3d%30%30%33%34%2d%35%33%31%38%26%76%6f%6c%3d%32%31%26%69%73%73%3d%36%26%72%61%6e%6b%3d%36&ei=RW1wVLnOMpKTuASYu4CoCw&usg=AFQjCNEYTvCfpvoNbK1Pvirjr2SnRlWfgA&bvm=bv.80185997,d.c2E) and on page 9, the paragraph before Proposition 5, it is said that let the vector field $\hat{X}$ on a manifold $M$ defined by an element $X$ in a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$.

How to define the vector field $\hat{X}$ on a manifold $M$ defined by an element $X$ in a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a Lie group acting on $M$. Then there's a Lie algebra homomorphism $\sigma: \mathfrak g \to \mathfrak X(M)$ by sending $A \in \mathfrak g$ to the vector field that generates the flow given by $\varphi_t(x) = \exp(tA)x$. I assume this is the way of passing from $\mathfrak g$ to $\mathfrak X(M)$ the authors refer to (without looking at the paper).